# Making a library or wrapper kind of thing to export functionality of a certain Application to different programming language

Tags: javascript, python, leaflet

I want to create a language-agnostic library for a map application I developed. The main purpose of the library is to allow the output of my application to be used in other programming languages. I'm not sure how to approach this or what components to include, but I believe it should act as a wrapper around my existing code. I have heard terms like SDK and APIs and wonder if they are relevant to my project. But it should be like one thing and can be used in many programming languages.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.